# How make a link by a click on a button inside an IonAlert (component ionic)

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, render, ionic4

I want to make a link by a click on a button inside an IonAlert. IonAlert is component I used to display an alert and I can interact with it by click either on cancel or confirm ( see the following picture)

[image]

I have the following code :

```
<Link to="/packed" className="item">

                <IonAlert
                    isOpen="true"
                    onDidDismiss={() => ""}
                    header={'Fin des check'}
                    message={'Tous les produits ont été checkés. Voulez-vous valider ces checks ?'}
                    buttons= {[
                        {
                          text: 'Cancel',
                          role: 'cancel',
                          cssClass: 'secondary',
                          handler: () => {
                            console.log('user cancel');
                          }
                        }, 
                        {
                          text: 'Confirm',
                          handler: () => {
                            CallApi();
                            console.log("user confirm");
                          }
                        }
                      ]}
                />
                  div
          </Link>
```

I just want to have a link if the user click on the button confirm. But I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Thank you for your reading !

Comment: What do you mean by "create a link"? You want it to open a webpage in the browser or something? If that is the case you can just use a custom function in the `Confirm` button's handler, similar to how you have `CallApi();`

Comment: A link in react allow to go to another page with another React component. I mean this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally resolve this problem but very simply ... Firstly, I've created a propriety in the state of the react component.

```
state = {
        redirectToDeliveries: false, //will allow or no the redirection to component Deliveries
    }
```

After this, when I click on my button I call my function which is in my handler .

```
if(this.state.numberOfCheck === this.state.numberOfProductsPerCommand) {
            button = <IonAlert
                isOpen="true"
                onDidDismiss={() => ""}
                header={'Fin des check'}
                message={'Tous les produits ont été checkés. Voulez-vous valider ces checks ?'}
                buttons= {[
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        role: 'cancel',
                        cssClass: 'secondary',
                    }, 
                    {
                        text: 'Confirm',
                        handler: () => {
                            this.setOrderStatus();
                        }
                    }
                ]}
            />;
        }
```

In this function, I just change the state of the propriety redirectToDeliveries.

```
setOrderStatus() {

        this.setState({redirectToDeliveries: true});

    }
```

And just before to verify my condition if, I created an other condition if which just check the value of this propriety.

```
if(this.state.redirectToDeliveries) {
            return <Redirect to='/' />
        }

        if(this.state.numberOfCheck === this.state.numberOfProductsPerCommand) {
            button = <IonAlert
                isOpen="true"
                onDidDismiss={() => ""}
                header={'Fin des check'}
                message={'Tous les produits ont été checkés. Voulez-vous valider ces checks ?'}
                buttons= {[
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        role: 'cancel',
                        cssClass: 'secondary',
                    }, 
                    {
                        text: 'Confirm',
                        handler: () => {
                            this.setOrderStatus();
                        }
                    }
                ]}
            />;
        }
```

All work.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm not an expert in React but as nobody has replied for 4 days I'll jump in and see if we can get you unstuck.

One option is to use the [InAppBrowser Ionic Native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser). Then you could write some code like this:

```
this.iab.create(link, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Another option is to use whatever the router api for React is. In Angular this would be something like injecting the router in to the constructor and then using  one of the navigate functions.

That's not going to solve your problem directly, but this should at least give you the theory to solve this problem yourself.